# How can I scroll through elements in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Roughly, I'd trying to make a series of buttons A B C D, where clicking on A scrolls you to B, clicking on B scrolls you to C, etc, and clicking on D scrolls you to A.

I have buttons ("tags") that all have the class `tag` and a specific tag, like `green`. I'm trying to make it so that clicking on a tag called "green" takes you to the next "green," unless it's the last one, in which case it starts over.

Here's what I've been trying:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    counter = 0
    $('.tag').click(function(){
        counter = counter + 1; 
        var scrollTo = '.' + $(this).text(); 
        scrollTo = $(scrollTo)      
        console.debug(scrollTo);
        len = scrollTo.length
        if ( counter > len-1 ) { 
            counter = 0; 
            scrollTo = $(scrollTo)[0]; 
        } else { 
            scrollTo = $(scrollTo)[counter]
        } 
        console.debug(scrollTo);
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scrollTo).parent().offset().top });
    }); 
});
```

This mostly works, but only if you start at the beginning. I'm trying to make it so that clicking on the 2nd "green" tag, it takes you to the 3rd, etc.

I know I'm making this unnecessarily convoluted. Is there an easier way?

Comment: It's a little hard without seeing an example of the markup, especially since the buttons text is used as a selector etc. The solution is probably to use the buttons index instead of a counter, or even DOM traversal to find the next element to scroll to etc.

Comment: I think the issue is that I can get a list of all the buttons with the tag, and I can get the current tag, but I don't know how to find out which of the list items is the one I'm currently on.

Comment: Does it have to scroll?  Could you just use anchors and bookmarks to jump to the next position?

Comment: To find out which one you're currently on, you probably need a system that checks the scroll position, and sets a flag on whatever is currently visible in the viewport etc. That's at least how it's usually done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to find index of current element:

```
    var counter = 0; 
    var scrollToSelector = '.' + $(this).text(); 
    var scrollTo = $(scrollToSelector);
    var self = this;
    scrollTo.each(function(i, e){
        if (e == self) {
            counter = i + 1;
        }
    });
    if (counter >= scrollTo.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like e==this for all instances of scrollTo.

Comment: You right - I missed the point that .each will change this to be current element in process. So we need to save this into variable for reference. I updated code.